# Find the eigenvalues ​and eigenvectors of a linear transformation in the general case

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

While preparing for a test, I was faced with the following task: Find the eigenvalues ​​and eigenvectors of a linear transformation $\phi$ specified by a matrix:

$$
A = (a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_n)^T(b_1, b_2,\ldots, b_n) \neq 0
$$

And also find a necessary and sufficient condition for its diagonalizability.

I understand how to find the eigenvalues ​​and eigenvectors of a linear transformation in a special case, but I don’t understand how to do it in such a general case. I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Are $a_i$ and $b_i$ elements of the underlying field or vectors? In the first case, the matrix $A$ is $1\times 1$.

Comment: @whpowell96 I think those $n$-tuples are supposed to be row vectors, making this $n \times n$, with rank $1$.

Comment: @whpowell96 yes, you are right in the task this was implied

Comment: This is a duplicate. Let us find some similar earlier post.

Comment: As you say, you can find the eigenvalues and egienvectors in a special case. Actually try a few special cases! What eigenvalues do you get? What are their multiplicities? What about their eigenspaces; how do they relate to the vectors you've chosen (are they parallel? Orthogonal?). With a couple of examples, I think you could quickly find a pattern and prove it.

Comment: Voted to close with the above duplicate. When thinking about this, consider the cases $Av$ when $v$ is a scalar multiple of $b^T$ and the case when $v$ is orthogonal to $b^T$.

Comment: I suggest just trying to solve for it. Write the eigenvector as $v = (v_1, \dots, v_n)$. Calculate the formula for $Av$ (and note that part of it is a dot product) and solve for $\lambda$ and $v$ such that $Av=\lambda v$. It's not that hard if you just plunge into the calculation.